# how to add the script type file to yii frame work?

Tags: yii

how i add this js file to yii framework.
we can add simple js file like that

> $scripts->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . 'dd.js?' . $this->version);

but now i want also to define my js file type such as type="text/babel"

```
< script type = "text/babel" src = "abc.js" >
```

Comment: Please yii1 or yii2 ?

Comment: I found the documentation on `registerScriptFile ()` at Yii Framework website, however, the following did not work for me : 
`$scripts->registerScriptFile ($baseUrl . '/js/views/Components.js?'. $this->version,CClientScript::POS_HEAD, array('type'=>'text/babel'));`  Link to reference : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail